# TensorFlow: Understanding the parameters returned by evaluate

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I've created a Linear classifier model using tensorflow. When I evaluate the model the following is returned.

```
accuracy: 0.975183
eval_auc: 0.534855
loss: 0.115239
```

Could somebody please explain me how eval_auc and loss is calculated? Thanks!

Comment: Add relevant pieces of code where `eval_auc` and `loss` operations are defined.

Comment: I'm not using custom operations for those. I used `tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier` to create the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval_auc` must be the AUC = Area Under the ROC Curve.
See explanation, for example, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it)

`loss` must be logloss = logarithmic loss.
See explanation, for example, [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-logarithmic-loss/)